# monotonic mapping from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

can someone please help me to find a mapping function which maps the whole real axis to (0,1). I want the function to be monotonic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0, 1)$$

$$f(x) = \dfrac{\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$x \mapsto \frac{1 + \frac{x}{1 + |x|}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the function $\arctan\colon (-\infty,+\infty) \rightarrow \left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right) $
and let 
$$f\colon \left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)\rightarrow(0,1),\quad x\mapsto ax+b$$
so we have
$$-\frac\pi2a+b=0\quad;\quad\frac\pi2a+b=1$$
hence we find
$$b=\frac12\quad;\quad a=\frac1\pi$$
now we take the desired function: $f\circ\arctan$

Answer (score 0):

It's not very hard to see by drawing the graph that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$$
defines a decreasing function from $(0,1)$ onto $\Bbb R$.  So you could take the inverse of this, which happens to be
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2}{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4}}\ .$$